# How to split text files into smaller files with numeric suffixes but no 0 prefix

Tags: bash, unix, split, command-line-interface

I have a large text file which I want to split into smaller files with the same amount of lines each and numeric suffixes. I know I can use split command like this:

```
split -d -l 2000 myBigFile.txt
```

However, this command will produce something like `file.00, file.01`, etc. I want `file.1, file.2, ..., file.10, ...`, i.e., start from 1 and no 0 prefix in the suffix.

Related question: instead of specify the number of lines in each file, can I use split command to specify number of output files (the number of lines per file will be automatically computed)?

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you want that? When you `ls` the files or `cat` them, they will now be out of order (`file.1`, `file.10`, `file.2` etc). Which is why there are zero padded.

Comment: Related question: read the `man` page: "-n, --number=CHUNKS generate CHUNKS output files.  See below [...] CHUNKS may be: N       split into N files based on size of input K/N".

Comment: I'm not sure you can avoid the number 0.  Using `csplit -k -n 1 -f file. myBigfile.txt file 2000 '{9}'` might work if your big file has up to 10 units, but the `-n 1` (on Mac OS X) stops generating files when it needs `file.10`.  Up to 100, you can use `-n 2` but that gives leading zeros on the first ten files.  And it still gives you `file.00` and there's a weird off-by-one for the first output file — so it isn't a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

With gnu split you can specify the starting index with this option instead of `-d`

```
--numeric-suffixes=1
```

but it will still be zero padded.

Comment: Using `-a 1` or `--suffix-length=1` works with GNU `split` as long as there are only files 1-9 in the output.  If there's more, it insists on 01, 02, etc.  I think that a renaming operation might be necessary: Perl-base rename can handle that — `rename 's/\.0+/./' file.0?`